# How to update bundle after install --standalone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have a developement server with several rails instances, that use

```
bundle install --standalone
```

Not sure on how the initial installation was done, but no system bundler is available for my user (and `bundle install --standalone` doesn't work for me). What is the correct way of updating bundles after the Gemfile update?

Added:
To make things clear, I have working installation, just don't know how to update it.
I think the way is:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/bin/bundle install --standalone
```

should check it a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I think that you need to go in and update your bundler gem file dependencies.

http://gembundler.com/v1.2/rationale.html

After updating your dependencies make sure they are installed.

http://gembundler.com/rails3.html

Hope that helps.